# yylineno has always the same value in yacc file

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc

for one project in compilers i have one problem in the syntax analyzer,
when i go to add a symbol in a symbol table, i take always the same value in yylineno...

i did this in the begining:

```
%{

    int yylex(void);
    int yyerror(char* yaccProvidedMessage);    
    extern int yylineno;     //i declare yylineno from the lexical analyzer
    extern char *yytext;
    extern FILE *yyin;       

    int scope=0;  
    int max_scope;
%}
```

and in the grammar when i go to add something in symbol table:

i.e

```
lvalue: ID {

        printf("<-ID");     
        add_data_to_symbol_table((char*)($1),scope,yylineno);
        printf("lineNO:%d",yylineno);

        }
        ;
```

in the output when i give an input 
with different lines it doesnt recognize the new line

```
if(x<=2)
{

    if(t<1)
    {
        k=2;   
    }
}
```

the lineNO never change,always have 1 as value...

any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using `yylineno` from `flex`, then you should probably add a line

```
%option yylineno
```

to your `flex` specification. Beware however that it is not advisable to export `yylineno` directly to your grammar, as your grammar may request look ahead tokens from the tokenizer and thus `yylineno` may already have been updated. The professed way of handling `yylineno` is through `yylval`. I've also seen that `bison` has new line-numbering features (see `@1` and `@@` etc.) that probably integrates more effortlessly with `flex`.

P.S: Look me talking about `bison`, where you only mentioned `yacc`. If you are committed to `yacc`, pass it through `yylval`.